# Graph plot not linking with 2 dropdown lists of Years and Months

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I wanted to integrate graph plot to two dropdown lists. One is for years and the other one is for months. After selecting any year from year dropdown and  month from months dropdown, I wanted the graph of the month from the year selected to be plotted. But I am not able to do this.
I have created the graph plots of the students joined on the days in the month.
It will be very grateful if any of you solve my doubt.
[Click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLdjg.png)

The graph plot of the selected month from the selected year should be displayed which shows the number of students joined on days of the selected month.
[Click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TZc1.png)

But I am getting this as the result. Please solve the issue .
Nothing is showing in the graph section in the web page.
[Click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUTc4.png)

My code-

```
dbc.Col([html.H4('Day Wise Joining In Interview Preparation'),], style={"margin-top": "60px", 'textAlign': 'center', "font-size": "70"}),
      html.Label(['Year'],style={'font-weight': 'bold',"margin-left": "38px"}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown_3',
            options=[
                {'label': '2022',  'value': '2022_Year'},
                {'label': '2023',  'value': '2023_Year'},
            ],
            
        style={"width": "60%", "verticalAlign": "middle", "margin-left": "20px", "margin-top": "10px"}),
    
    
    html.Label(['Month'],style={'font-weight': 'bold',"margin-left": "38px","margin-top": "10px"}),
    dcc.Dropdown(
           id='dropdown_4',
           options=[
                {'label': 'January', 'value': 'plotd_2023_jan'},
                {'label': 'February', 'value': 'plotd_2022_feb'},
                {'label': 'March', 'value': 'plotd_2022_mar'},
                {'label': 'April', 'value': 'plotd_2022_apr'},
                {'label': 'May', 'value': 'plotd_2022_may'},
                {'label': 'June', 'value': 'plotd_2022_jun'},
                {'label': 'July', 'value': 'plotd_2022_jul'},
                {'label': 'August', 'value': 'plotd_2022_aug'},
                {'label': 'September', 'value': 'plotd_2022_sep'},
                {'label': 'October', 'value': 'plotd_2022_oct'},
                {'label': 'November', 'value': 'plotd_2022_nov'},
                {'label': 'December', 'value': 'plotd_2022_dec'},
           ],
           
        style={"width": "60%", "verticalAlign": "middle", "margin-left": "20px", "margin-top": "10px"}),
                          
    (dcc.Graph(id='graph_2')), 
])         

@app.callback(
    Output('graph_2', 'figure'),
    [Input(component_id='dropdown_3', component_property='value'),
     Input(component_id='dropdown_4', component_property='value')]
)
def drop_chart2(year_value,month_value):
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_feb'):        
        plotd_2022_feb = px.bar(days_2022_feb, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_feb.update_layout(bargap=0.2,height=722)
        return plotd_2022_feb
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_mar'):
        plotd_2022_mar = px.bar(days_2022_mar, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_mar.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_mar
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_apr'):
        plotd_2022_apr = px.bar(days_2022_apr, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_apr.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_apr
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_may'):
        plotd_2022_may = px.bar(days_2022_may, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_may.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_may
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_jun'):
        plotd_2022_jun = px.bar(days_2022_jun, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_jun.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_jun
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_jul'):
        plotd_2022_jul = px.bar(days_2022_jul, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_jul.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_jul    
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_aug'):
        plotd_2022_aug = px.bar(days_2022_aug, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_aug.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_aug  
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_sep'):
        plotd_2022_sep = px.bar(days_2022_sep, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_sep.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_sep
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_oct'):
        plotd_2022_oct = px.bar(days_2022_oct, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_oct.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_oct
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_nov'):
        plotd_2022_nov = px.bar(days_2022_nov, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_nov.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_nov
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2022_dec'):
        plotd_2022_dec = px.bar(days_2022_dec, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_dec.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_dec
    if (year_value == '2023_Year' &  month_value == 'plotd_2023_jan'):
        plotd_2023_jan = px.bar(days_2023_jan, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2023_jan.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2023_jan
```

Comment: I think you should post sample code of your, not image.

Comment: Ok, posted the code

Comment: Can you provide sample dataframe too? I want to run by myself

Comment: @hoatran I wanted to share you the .ipynb notebook for better understanding. How to share it to you ?

Comment: You can use google colab or just upload somewhere can download (google drive...)

Comment: @hoatran I have provided the link of notebook in drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UWlf4tlO3p7l1lU_DHN1gnRqRQjfah7v/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @hoatran Is the notebook working on your computer ?

Comment: @hoatran What to do if there is a plot fr different month and different year . Like if I select 2022 and january a different plot has to show and if I select 2023 and January a different plot should come up. How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking your notebook I think you should change as below, instead of `&` you should use `and` and I added `PreventUpdate` to make graphs not update when it doesn't have value from dropdown:

```
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Col([
        html.H1('Hackveda '),
        html.H2('Statistics'),

    ], style={'textAlign': 'center'}),

    

    html.Div([
      html.H4(children='Students Joined in Year',style={"margin-left": "26px", "margin-top": "20px"}),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig_1
    ),
    html.Div([
      html.H4(children='Number of Students in Course',style={"margin-left": "26px"}),
      dcc.Graph(id='graph2',figure=fig_2),
   ])
    ])
,



        dbc.Col([html.H4('Total Interns Monthly Breakdown'),], style={"margin-top": "60px", 'textAlign': 'center', "font-size": "70"}),
        html.Label(['Year'],style={'font-weight': 'bold',"margin-left": "38px"}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown',
            options=[
                {'label': '2017', 'value': 'fig_2017'},
                {'label': '2018', 'value': 'fig_2018'},
                {'label': '2019', 'value': 'fig_2019'},
                {'label': '2020', 'value': 'fig_2020'},
                {'label': '2021', 'value': 'fig_2021'},
                {'label': '2022', 'value': 'fig_2022'},
                {'label': '2023', 'value': 'fig_2023'},
                    ],
            value='fig_2022',
            style={"width": "60%", "verticalAlign": "middle", "margin-left": "20px", "margin-top": "10px"}),
        
    (dcc.Graph(id='graph')),
    
         dbc.Col([html.H4('Students Enrolled In Interview Preparation'),
                  html.H5('Monthly Breakdown'),], style={"margin-top": "60px", 'textAlign': 'center', "font-size": "70"}),
        html.Label(['Year'],style={'font-weight': 'bold',"margin-left": "38px"}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown_1',
            options=[
                {'label': '2022', 'value': 'plot_2022'},
                {'label': '2023', 'value': 'plot_2023'},
        ],
        value='plot_2022',
        style={"width": "60%", "verticalAlign": "middle", "margin-left": "20px", "margin-top": "10px"}),
    (dcc.Graph(id='graph_1')),
    
    
    dbc.Col([html.H4('Day Wise Joining In Interview Preparation'),], style={"margin-top": "60px", 'textAlign': 'center', "font-size": "70"}),
      html.Label(['Year'],style={'font-weight': 'bold',"margin-left": "38px"}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown_3',
            options=[
                {'label': '2022',  'value': '2022_Year'},
                {'label': '2023',  'value': '2023_Year'},
            ],
            
        style={"width": "60%", "verticalAlign": "middle", "margin-left": "20px", "margin-top": "10px"}),
    
    
    html.Label(['Month'],style={'font-weight': 'bold',"margin-left": "38px","margin-top": "10px"}),
    dcc.Dropdown(
           id='dropdown_4',
           options=[
                {'label': 'January', 'value': 'plotd_2023_jan'},
                {'label': 'February', 'value': 'plotd_2022_feb'},
                {'label': 'March', 'value': 'plotd_2022_mar'},
                {'label': 'April', 'value': 'plotd_2022_apr'},
                {'label': 'May', 'value': 'plotd_2022_may'},
                {'label': 'June', 'value': 'plotd_2022_jun'},
                {'label': 'July', 'value': 'plotd_2022_jul'},
                {'label': 'August', 'value': 'plotd_2022_aug'},
                {'label': 'September', 'value': 'plotd_2022_sep'},
                {'label': 'October', 'value': 'plotd_2022_oct'},
                {'label': 'November', 'value': 'plotd_2022_nov'},
                {'label': 'December', 'value': 'plotd_2022_dec'},
           ],
           
        style={"width": "60%", "verticalAlign": "middle", "margin-left": "20px", "margin-top": "10px"}),
                          
    (dcc.Graph(id='graph_2')), 
])         
                     

@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input(component_id='dropdown', component_property='value')]
)
def drop_chart(value):
    if value == 'fig_2017':        
        fig_2017 = px.bar(final_6, x="Students", y="months", orientation='h')
        return fig_2017
    if value == 'fig_2018':
        fig_2018 = px.bar(final_5, x="Students", y="months", orientation='h')
        return fig_2018
    if value == 'fig_2019':
        fig_2019 = px.bar(final_4, x="Students", y="months", orientation='h')
        return fig_2019
    if value == 'fig_2020':
        fig_2020 = px.bar(final_3, x="Students", y="months", orientation='h')
        return fig_2020
    if value == 'fig_2021':
        fig_2021 = px.bar(final_2, x="Students", y="months", orientation='h')
        return fig_2021
    if value == 'fig_2022':
        fig_2022 = px.bar(final_1, x="Students", y="months", orientation='h')
        return fig_2022
    if value == 'fig_2023':
        fig_2023 = px.bar(final_7, x="Students", y="months", orientation='h')
        return fig_2023
    
@app.callback(
    Output('graph_1', 'figure'),
    [Input(component_id='dropdown_1', component_property='value')]
)    
def drop_chart1(value_1):
    if value_1 == 'plot_2022':        
        plot_2022 = px.bar(intprep_2022, x="Students", y="months", orientation='h')
        return plot_2022
    if value_1 == 'plot_2023':
        plot_2023 = px.bar(intprep_2023, x="Students", y="months", orientation='h')
        return plot_2023
    
@app.callback(
    Output('graph_2', 'figure'),
    [Input(component_id='dropdown_3', component_property='value'),
     Input(component_id='dropdown_4', component_property='value')]
)
def drop_chart2(year_value,month_value):
    if (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_feb'):        
        plotd_2022_feb = px.bar(days_2022_feb, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_feb.update_layout(bargap=0.2,height=722)
        return plotd_2022_feb
    elif (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_mar'):
        plotd_2022_mar = px.bar(days_2022_mar, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_mar.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_mar
    elif (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_apr'):
        plotd_2022_apr = px.bar(days_2022_apr, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_apr.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_apr
    elif (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_may'):
        plotd_2022_may = px.bar(days_2022_may, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_may.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_may
    elif (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_jun'):
        plotd_2022_jun = px.bar(days_2022_jun, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_jun.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_jun
    elif (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_jul'):
        plotd_2022_jul = px.bar(days_2022_jul, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_jul.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_jul    
    elif (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_aug'):
        plotd_2022_aug = px.bar(days_2022_aug, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_aug.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_aug  
    elif (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_sep'):
        plotd_2022_sep = px.bar(days_2022_sep, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_sep.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_sep
    elif (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_oct'):
        plotd_2022_oct = px.bar(days_2022_oct, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_oct.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_oct
    elif (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_nov'):
        plotd_2022_nov = px.bar(days_2022_nov, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_nov.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_nov
    elif (year_value == '2022_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2022_dec'):
        plotd_2022_dec = px.bar(days_2022_dec, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2022_dec.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2022_dec
    elif (year_value == '2023_Year' and  month_value == 'plotd_2023_jan'):
        plotd_2023_jan = px.bar(days_2023_jan, x="Date", y="Students", orientation='v')
        plotd_2023_jan.update_layout(bargap=0.23,height=724)
        return plotd_2023_jan
    else:       
        raise PreventUpdate
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(port=1085)
```

[image]

Comment: What to do if there is a plot fr different month and different year  .                                              Like if I select 2022 and january a different plot has to show and if I select 2023 and January a different plot should come up. How to fix this issue.